# Getting a return value from submit() via jquery

Tags: jquery, submit, return-value

I have a page with multiple forms on it. Each form has it's own Save button which validates and displays error messages using .ajax() to post (not a normal post method). I also have a Next button outside of the forms which is caught by jQuery click() handler. This function goes through each form and calls $(formname).submit() for each.

Ultimately I need to know if the individual forms passed validation in order to determine if a redirect should happen. I have added, `return false;` in the else statement of the validate check in the submit function but I cannot see how to retrieve it.

Having `alert($(this).submit());` just returns the object not a return value. Without re-coding the whole $.ajax post code for each form, is there anyway I can find out if the submit failed??

```
//next button click
$('#savenext').click(function () {
    var finalsuccess;
    $('.record_form').each(function (index) {
        alert($(this).submit()); //I want this to be true or false
    });
//forms each have their own submit handler
$(formname).submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    if($(form).valid()) { //validate the form, return false if it is not valid. 
    //Post the form to the action if it passes
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text json",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                //does some success messages here
            },
        });
    }
    else {
        return false;
        }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: why not use `jquery Validation` plugin instead? :-/

Comment: Hi @Dave. The validation all works swimmingly so I don't need to change any of that. I just need to figure out the best way to get a response back from form.submit(). Is there something in that plugin that allows for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone needs to know, I found no way to get the submit to return a success value. In the end I changed the ajax post to be async: false, put that in a function which returned a boolean set by either the success or error event of the ajax post. Not as quick because of the succession of server calls but I will add a loading dialog to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while searching for a solution to my problem and couldnt find anything that worked. I ended up having to 'hook' the jQuery submit function, code below incase someone also has the same issue.

```
// override jQuery.submit() so that it returns true/false rather than a jQuery object
var original_submit = jQuery.fn.submit;
jQuery.fn.submit = function() {
    // we are only interested in the .submit() trigger calls
    if (arguments.length == 0)
    {
        var ret = $(this).triggerHandler("submit");

        // assume true unless we specifically returned false
        return ret === false ? false : true;
    }

    // fallback to original function
    return original_submit.apply(this, arguments);
};
```